# Como recuperar o IP de um cliente?

Tags: node.js, express.js, ip, ipv4

Estou trabalhando em meu primeiro projeto profissional utilizando Node.js. Nele faço alterações em grupos de segurança de instâncias EC2 AWS.

Um dos dados no qual o sistema realiza atualizações é o IP do cliente. Atualmente estou utilizando a API Ipify pare recuperar o IP. Porém a API está retornando o IP do servidor, e preciso que seja o IP do cliente.

O code sendo utilizado na API está assim:

```
const http = require('http')
http.get({ host: 'api.ipify.org', port: 80, path: '/' }, function (resp) {
      resp.on('data', function (ip) {
      const ipCliente = ip.toString('utf8') + '/32'
```

Em uma questão parecida, deram a solução de ao invés de utilizar a API, simplesmente tratar a requisição da rota da seguinte forma:

```
const ipCliente = req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Porém o ip retornado é `::1`.

Comment: Eu li sobre esse `Ipify` e o que ele faz é retornar o seu próprio ip publico, é isso mesmo? Quando eu preciso capturar o ip de uma _request_ eu uso algo como [@supercharge/request-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supercharge/request-ip) junto ao Express. Chegou a testar com esse pacote? Imagino que `req.connection.remoteAddress` seja do Express, mas voce tentou `req.ip`?

Comment: Ler o cabeçalho [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) da requisição resolve o seu problema? `const ipCliente = req.headers['X-Forwarded-For']`

Comment: Senhores, ambos os comandos sugeridos me retornaram  ::1 . Estou suspeitando de que seja algum bug relacionado ao local host

Comment: Problema resolvido! Como estava trabalhando com testes em localhost, o método req.ip estava me retornando o ::1 pois se trata de um prefixo do futuro ipv6. Ao realizar o teste já na EC2 o IP foi resgatado corretamente. Grato pela ajuda de todos!

Answer (score 1):

Eu trabalho com golang, usando EC2 e também já tive problemas similares. Em GO eu costumo trabalhar com o Framework GIN para gerenciar as rotas e endpoints, e para obter o endereço de IP da requisição eu uso a função `ClientIP()`.

Analisando os códigos fontes do Framework ele explica que para pegar o IP verdadeiro do cliente temos que pegar o Header `X-Forwarded-For`, caso ele não exista então tentamos pegar o Header `X-Real-Ip`, além disso ele também tenta usar o Header `X-Appengine-Remote-Addr`, e em últimos casos ele usa o RemoteAddress.

Acredito eu que essa seja a melhor forma e a mesma precisa para tentar obter o IP verdadeiro do cliente.

```
// ClientIP implements a best effort algorithm to return the real client IP, it parses 
// X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For in order to work properly with reverse-proxies such us: nginx or haproxy. 
// Use X-Forwarded-For before X-Real-Ip as nginx uses X-Real-Ip with the proxy's IP.
```

Fonte: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/7742ff50e0a05d079a0c468ccfbf7c6ecfe2414b/context.go#L728

Comment: O que o Gin faz é inseguro, o `X-Forwarded-For` pode ser forjado.

Comment: Aparentemente, alguém já reportou isso: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/pull/2474. Inclusive com um CVE (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-28483). Até hoje eles não corrigiram. O CVE especifica: "This affects all versions of package github.com/gin-gonic/gin. When gin is exposed directly to the internet, a client's IP can be spoofed by setting the X-Forwarded-For header.". Isso só será seguro se tiver realmente certeza de que o `X-Forwarded-For` foi removido em algum proxy reverso (e ele foi quem definiu o header) e que a conexão é dele (e não for fora).

Comment: Eduardo, infelizmente não posso usar esse método o sistema que estou desenvolvendo é para configurações de segurança do firewall de instâncias, e qualquer pequena brecha deixa o sistema inválido.

Comment: Então infelizmente não sei oque fazer ou como te ajudar, não entendo muito dessa parte de redes e configurações de instancia e como tudo isso funciona. Eu apenas tenho conhecimento um pouco de como o GIN funciona e eu só usei para finalidades que não se importavam tanto com a precisão do IP.